STM32: Can I use the Data RAM to store data persistently?
I'm currently working with an STM32F1 MCU and I'm storing data persistently in Flash memory.
I'm looking, however, at this STM32H7 and it has very little user flash memory (enough for my main application code but not enough for the auxiliary data that I'm using), but it has almost 10x more Data RAM.
Can I use that Data RAM to store data persistently as I'm doing with Flash memory?

RAM is a somewhat sloppily used term, the industry standard meaning of it isn't so much "random access memory" but rather "fast volatile memory that needs continuous supply to refresh the cells". So it can't store persistent data when you remove the supply. It might not even be able to reliably store data across MCU resets.
If you ignore Mouser and instead first check with ST as you ought to do, then we can see that STM32 H7 series support flash up to 2Mb, with the 64kb version being the smallest one. Pick the correct part using ST's site and documentation.
When you are sure about what you want, then you can visit sites like Mouser to purchase it. It's a very bad idea to use Mouser specifically at the design stage, since they are infamous for frequently displaying wrong technical characteristics for the parts they sell.

Catalog houses are especially bad at characterizing complex chips like MCUs

No; RAM contents is lost when MCU is unpowered.
The H7 you are looking at with 64 KB of flash must be an "application processor" intended to have enough built-in flash to load the application into RAM from some external storage, such as SPI flash.

Conversely, it can be used as NVRAM if the MCU is persistently (e.g. battery) powered.

Particularly for the faster and more complex MCUs, and the more complex and demanding applications that might use them, utilizing more of the total 4GB address space becomes very helpful.
Consider the FMC (Flexible Memory Controller), a bus interface compatible with SRAM, Flash, SDRAM and more.
If you like, an external SRAM can be powered by backup battery, preserving its contents as NVRAM.  This might be used as if a high speed, unlimited-write Flash storage, with perhaps a bit better density than FeRAM or related technologies can offer.
The SPI Flash system may also be of interest, offering quite high bandwidth despite the serial interface.  A fairly small onboard Flash might be used to load the main application, or to store other core functionality, while external storage (FMC, SPI, µSD, USB, etc.) is used for applications and data storage.
This greatly reduces the demand for onboard/internal Flash, allowing more area to be dedicated to SRAM: consider structuring your application to load overlays in local RAM, permanently (shadow ROM), as overlays, or a kernel-controlled cache.  This allows significant optimization over execution from Flash, especially over external or serial bus.

The STM32H7 MCU you've chosen has 4kB of "Backup SRAM" (datasheet pg.26 section 3.3.3).
So if you attach a battery to the appropriate power pin (VBAT), then the contents of that memory block will be retained through power cycles.
This only applies to that 4kB block though - the rest of the RAM is not powered by this VBAT supply and will be lost if the main power source is removed.
